# Remove numbers from python dictionary make the information the parent of all data to store in spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

Is it possible to remove the numbers as parents (0,1,2) from the data below and set the 'information' as the parent in the dictionary

I have this result set from api as a dictionary:

```
    {0:{
'information': [{
    'created': '2020-10-26T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random1',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random2',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-27T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random3',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random4',
    'published': 'YES',
}]
},
{1:{
'information': [{
    'created': '2020-10-26T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random5',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random6',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-27T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random7',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random8',
    'published': 'YES',
}]
},
{2:{
'information': [{
    'created': '2020-10-26T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random9',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random10',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-27T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random11',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random12',
    'published': 'YES',
}]
}
```

I want to remove the numbers 0,1,2 and make 'information' the parent of information with created, title, published values beneath them, like:

```
{
'information': [{
    'created': '2020-10-26T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random1',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-11-06T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random2',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-27T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random3',
    'published': 'YES',
}, {
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random4',
    'published': 'YES',
},{
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random5',
    'published': 'YES',
},{
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random6',
    'published': 'YES',
},{
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random7',
    'published': 'YES',
},{
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random8',
    'published': 'YES',
},{
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random9',
    'published': 'YES',
},{
    'created': '2020-10-29T00:00:00+00:00',
    'title': 'Random10',
    'published': 'YES',
}]
}
```

Why I want to do this is because I then want to store created, title & published into a dataframe like this:

```
spark.createDataFrame(json_data['results']).show()
```

Is it possible to do this, or is there a better way to just store that data into a dataframe?

Edit:

The creation of the input json was through looping through an array of title, after retrieving the response assigning it to a dictionary like:

```
  json_data={}

  title = ["Random1", "Random2","Random3"]

  for i in range(len(title)):
      response = requests.post(url, data=payload_json)
      json_data[i] = response.json()
```

Comment: is your input json correct ??

Comment: @Srinivas edited above how I append the json data to the dictionary

Comment: your input json seems not correct, can you add correct json.

Comment: @Srinivas thats how I append it from the api call into json_data.

Comment: You can try `json_data[i] = list(response.values())[0].json` on the last line
I'd like to test this myself but something seems off in your API response and I can't replicate this.

Comment: You can load api result into dataframe and do transformation in spark.

Comment: @WildWilyWilly response has no attribute values

Comment: @Srinivas how can I do this?

Comment: can you post your api json (check if format of json is correct - ```sonformatter.org```) without modification ?

Comment: @Srinivas json shows incorrect after adding it into json_data[i] the actual result. From the api the json is correct, but it loops through and appends it to the dict which makes it invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this script meets the conditions.

```py
combined_data={"information":[]}
title = ["Random1", "Random2","Random3"]

for i in range(len(title)):
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload_json)
    json_data_tmp = response.json()
    for v in json_data_tmp.values():
        if type(v)!=dict:
            continue
        combined_data["information"]+=v["information"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required

Comment: Now I get - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: maybe there are exceptions (not dict). I edit answer again.

Comment: looks like the code doesn't even reach combined_data += it ends up being empty

Comment: okay I got it to work as the values were lists by changing the code to !=list and also appending it like: combined_data["information"]+=v. But now the issue is how to convert to a dataframe by having the data as a flat file, rather than array values within each column